# jQuery doesn't work after pagination is loaded via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery script doesn't work after the same HTML has been loaded via AJAX, how to fix it please help me..

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#country').keyup(function(){  
       var query = $(this).val();  
       if(query != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"live_search",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{query:query},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#countryList').fadeIn();  
                      $('#countryList').html(data);  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  }); 
  $(document).on('click', '.li', function(){ 
       var query_1 = $(this).val(); 
       $('#country').val($(this).text());  
       $('#countryList').fadeOut();
       $('#search').click();
  });  
  });
```

Comment: Can you give us an example on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Delegate all you events

```
 $('body').on('keyup','#country',function(){});
```